# Extjs4 How to Call a function with parameters?

Tags: model-view-controller, function, extjs

This code doesn't work propely: I call a function passing a variable
What's the correct way to do this? Any suggests?

```
Ext.define('DigitalPaper.view.DirTree' ,{
    extend: 'Ext.TreePanel',
    requires: ['Ext.window.MessageBox'],
    id: "DirTree",
    store: 'DirTree',
    alias : 'widget.DirTree',
    title : 'Cartelle',
    rootVisible: true,
    useArrows: true,
    scope: this,
    selectNode: undefined,

initComponent: function() {
    //HERE: 
    this.assocFolderColumnset(id);

    this.callParent(arguments);
}

,assocFolderColumnset: function (id){
    console.log(id);
}
```

});

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Correction to the code

```
this.assocFolderColumnset(this.id);
```

and in assocFolderColumnset

```
,assocFolderColumnset: function (id){
    this.id = id;
    console.log(id);
}
```